# Amazon S3 as cdn copying images from my server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I have searched a lot on this but all I get is using CloudFront (CDN) in collaboration with S3.

I want to do something different.

CloudFront works as a CDN with its Origin set to either my domain where images are, or S3.

If I set it to my domain, there is an issue of having my hosting space used.

If I use it with S3, the question is, how to get my images to S3 without much hassle? In case of CDN, this is automatic, as every call to CloudFront copies the image from my server automatically.

Is it possible that CloudFront works with S3 but if image is not present on S3, it copies it from my server to S3?

Or may be S3 itself works as CDN (best solution). I have seen on some sites that they use s3 urls for hosting their images, like this:
https://retsimages.s3.amazonaws.com/14/A10363214_6.jpg

How is that possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question but possibly a webmastering question for https://webmaster.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I set it to my domain, there is an issue of having my hosting space used.

More expensive than the storage space is the cost of having a server sitting there ready to handle the request.  Your application logic konws when the images change; that's the time to put them in S3.

> how to get my images to S3 without much hassle?

There's an SDK for just about every language, so upload the image as it comes in.  Use `s3cmd sync` to move the images you have.  Then you can just turn off your server.

> Or may be S3 itself works as CDN

CloudFront can use a customer provided dns name *and matching certificate* so that you can use a custom domain with https.  It can integrate into AWS WAF which S3 cannot directly.  Otherwise, CDN behaves similarly to s3.  CloudFront should provide better caching and endpoint locality, but you'll see little functional difference at low volumes.  Neither is read-after-write consistent, but Cloudfront caches additionally.  Pricing is unlikely to make CloudFront cheaper for most uses.

Comment: The part with `s3cmd sync` seems promising, is there something similar for php? May be I can sync with s3 and then delete images from server. This way I can use the s3 bucket url as well

Comment: yeah, exactly.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-examples-creating-buckets.html.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that CloudFront works with S3 but if image is not present on S3, it copies it from my server to S3?

Close.

CloudFront does have a feature that would help move you in this direction -- [origin groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html).  Create an origin group with S3 as primary and your server as secondary. Any time CloudFront encounters a cache miss, it will first check S3, and only if the image is not there, it will retry by sending the request to your server.  It will cache the response, but it will not remember the source of the object -- so subsequent requests on future cache misses for the same object will always try S3 first.

This means *something* on your server needs to be responsible for ultimately moving images to S3 -- but as long as the image exists in one place or the other, the image will be served by CloudFront and cached in CloudFront in the edge or edges (up to two -- one global/outer, one regional/inner) that handled the request.